# Turtle constipation issue

Tags: turtles

My turtle has constipation problem now and then earlier she has went under a surgery 5 years back as her tissues were out now again we see her tail is swollen and it has become tight not able to poop and not eating
We tried warm water remedy but no sign of tail getting back to normal

Comment: Is it a male or female? How does it live (basking area, how much water)? Which size is it? Female become egg bound often, if they havw no area to lay their eggs. They are able to produce eggs, even without seen a male ever. Eggs and poop come from the same opening in turtles tail.